# How to find the ends with restrictions function $f(x,y)=4x^2+2y^2+10$, subject to $4x^2+y^2=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I've tried using Lagrange multipliers, but my problem is the equation system:
$$\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
 8x=\alpha(8x) \\
 4y=\alpha(2y) \\
 4x^2+y^2-4=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

I do not know what to do in this step

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
(Without Lagrange)

Under the restriction your function is

$$
f(x,y) = y^2 + 14
$$
Since $0\leq y^2 \leq 4$, you can find the end points pretty fast.